# Seasoned Admins: Can you confirm this suspscion? Gitlab & Lets Encrypt

Tags: server, dns, nginx, ssl

Using [this article](https://webnugget.de/setting-up-gitlab-with-free-ssl-certs-from-lets-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04/) I am trying to configure gitlab to use Lets Encrypt certificates to secure gitlab. Within the last hour I have configured the A record for my domain (codebase.ozpri.com @ afraid.org) and it seems to resolve on my computer, however when I try to create certificates based on the instructions in the article I get the following error:

```
Failed authorization procedure. codebase.ozpri.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization ::      Invalid response from http://codebase.ozpri.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/j1426HrsqkGIRuC6ilOCi9nLlW9fJ3t3GK8ABJucMD4: "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head prefix='og: http://ogp.me/ns#'>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta content='IE=edge' http-equiv"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: codebase.ozpri.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://codebase.ozpri.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/j1426HrsqkGIRuC6ilOCi9nLlW9fJ3t3GK8ABJucMD4:
   "<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang='en'>
   <head prefix='og: http://ogp.me/ns#'>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta content='IE=edge' http-equiv"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

**My Suspicion:** 
A. I need to give the DNS records time to propogate before running the command to create certificates. however, it looks like it's hitting my server so I'm not sure.  Is this correct or is there something else I need to investigate? I've gone through the instructions line by line and am unable to figure out what I could be doing wrong.
B. Instead of going to .well-known lets encrypt is getting the login page of gitlab

A Couple things to note:

1. When I install Apache and go to my website on a give web browser apache loads.
2. When I run gitlab over http, it responds normally.

Can anyone give me some advice on resolving this?